# linux/kernel.h : No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile, header-files

I am going to write a Hello World module in Ubuntu 10.10 (with the kernel 2.6.35-28-generic). Headers are located:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-28-generic
```

hello.c:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h> 
#include <linux/module.h>

int init_module(void)
{
    printk("Hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk("Goodbye\n");
}
```

and Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -DMODULE -D__KERNEL__
hello.o: hello.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c hello.c
    echo insmod hello.o to install
    echo rmmod to delete
```

There is an error while **make**:

> hello.c:1: fatal error:  linux/kernel.h : No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

How do I solve this?

Comment: guy, is this work? i've done all  that is written in answer that you chose as solution.  but i still  get "linux/kernel.h nu such file". i've browsed whole internet, but  nothing successful. i'm using ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Yes it is. The code in the question at the moment of publishing had a simple mistake: **there was space characters** (' ') inside the `#include <linux/kernel.h>` because of I had just copied the code from HTML page with the simple driver example. The second problem is solved by an answer I marked as solution. Check the link you have create is valid and follows to the right path, check if the path /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r) exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have /usr/src/linux symbolic link to your /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-28-generic ?
If not then create one using following commands

```
# cd /usr/src
# ln -sfn linux-headers-2.6.35-28-generic linux
```

Comment: I have created: ivan@ivan-MS-N031:/usr/src$ ls -l
total 73080
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root src        31 2011-04-10 14:57 linux -> linux-headers-2.6.35-28-generic
but error still appeared...

Comment: Ooops... There was an spaces in < linux/kernel.h >

Comment: i didn't do space, i 've done all what is written here, but error appears still: hello.c:1: fatal error: linux/kernel.h : No such file or directory compilation terminated.

Answer (score 7):

You can't just use a traditional-style `Makefile` with Linux kernel modules; while you *might* be able to force something to work, it'll be a painful experience.

Start by reading the `Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt` file; it'll describe exactly what you need to do when writing a module `Makefile` so that it can hook neatly into the kernel's `Kbuild` environment. Your `Makefile` will probably look something like this:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
# kbuild part of makefile
obj-m  := 8123.o
8123-y := 8123_if.o 8123_pci.o 8123_bin.o

else
# normal makefile
KDIR ?= /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD

# Module specific targets
genbin:
    echo "X" > 8123_bin.o_shipped

endif
```

Please trust me on this; while you might think you're "just one small change" from getting your own `Makefile` to work, even minor changes in kernel version will completely destroy your build all over again. Just take the hour now to write a `Kbuild`-compatible `Makefile` for your module. I wasted weeks of my life trying to maintain a pre-existing `Makefile` when the `Kbuild` infrastructure was introduced. Every new kernel caused me to lose *hours* of productivity.

Answer (score 3):

For me this file ("linux/kernel.h") is in the package linux-libc-dev (Kubuntu 10.10).

Comment: libc  is library for  c programming language. how can this touch linux/module.h ?

Comment: @shbk I was referring to the error message about "linux/kernel.h" not module.h. Here you can see the content of the package: http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/i386/linux-libc-dev/filelist

Answer (score 2):

just as what @sarnold said , you should use the different Makefile.Just as following:

> obj-m += hello.o
>
> all:
>       make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

and use the command:

> insmod hello.ko

to install this module.